# How to set the width of FeedInput control

Tags: sapui5

```
<FeedInput post="onPost" showIcon="false" width="200em"/>
```

This statement is not working. I tried to inspect element.

```
min-width: auto
```

How to override it without CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Panel>
    <l:Grid binding="" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop" hSpacing="2" defaultSpan="L6 M6 S12">
        <l:content>
            <FeedInput post="onPost" showIcon="false" placeholder="{i18n>WriteShiftNotes}" width="100em">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S12" linebreakL="true" linebreakM="true" linebreakS="true"/>
                </layoutData>
            </FeedInput>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
</Panel>
```